# Swagger/Openapi - How to document imported modules in a Spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi

I have an authentication module which is imported inside our projects to provide authentication related APIs.

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.my.package.ldap.security"})
@EnableCaching
@EnableRetry
public class ApplicationConfig {
...
}
```

I've configured Swagger/OpenAPI in my projects and I wish to find a way to manage these imported endpoints:

[image]

Specifically, I wish to set an order on the Example object's fields. Right now it is sorted alphabetically by default.
The reason for doing that is because a lot of these fields are "optional" and we have to remove these fields every time from the example object in order to authenticate a user which is a waste of time.

I've tried annotating the Object with `@JsonPropertyOrder` but it makes no change:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "domain",
    "username",
    "password"
})
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Note that JSON by specification is unordered. It should never matter in which order the fields are in. Given this, I always feel itchy when I see the use of `@JsonPropertyOrder`.

Comment: Why should it not matter? I have a bunch of fairly valid use cases for ordering fields in a certain way. In this case, a lot of these fields are "optional" and we have to remove these fields every time from the example object in order to authenticate a user which is a waste of time

Comment: Why would the position in a structure matter to a consumer that reads or parses values based on keys? It does not make any sense. Also, I feel like your 'fairly valid use cases' can be fixed by either using different DTOs or reconfiguring the objectmapper to your needs.

Comment: As I've clearly shared the swagger structure and even mentioned the same in title, it's not for end user but for developers.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps you misunderstood. I was not planning to make this into an argument. I was simply expressing the fact that JSON is unordered by specification (a lot of people overlook that fact), perhaps in order to make you rethink why you would want to use the annotation in the first place. If you really feel you need your json fields ordered and you think you have legitimate reasons to do so, I'm certainly not preventing you.

Comment: okay, there are valid cases for using the annotation but let's not go there as it's not related. Here, I've added the annotation just for trial and error to manage the order of "Example" object generated by Swagger which of course is not working so the annotation is not the solution.

Comment: As you use `Spring-Boot`, you probably use `Springfox`, which completely ignores the `@JsonPropertyOrder` annotation. It does come however with it's own annotation that you can use: `@ApiModelProperty` where you can pass a position to the property. https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2418
Update: depending on the version, also `ApiModelProperty` is broken
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3391

Comment: @NicoVanBelle the problem is these endpoints are part of an externally imported module. So i don't have direct access to these APIs or underlying model classes.

Comment: Then I think the best way to move forward is to implement a `WebMvcSwaggerTransformationFilter` that reads the definitions from the external module and then transforms them, sorting the properties of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small POC. It isn't pretty or very extendible, but it does work as intended. Perhaps one could make it more flexible, re-using the property position on the metadata object, but this example does not include that. This way you can loop definitions and models, manually doing the work that the framework fails to do at the moment.

Also, be sure not to make this too heavy because it will be executed every time someone opens up the swagger documentation. It's a piece of middleware that transforms the original Swagger API definition structure. It does not change the original one.

```java
@Order(SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER)
public class PropertyOrderTransformationFilter implements WebMvcSwaggerTransformationFilter {

    @Override
    public Swagger transform(final SwaggerTransformationContext<HttpServletRequest> context) {
        Swagger swagger = context.getSpecification();
        Model model = swagger.getDefinitions().get("applicationUserDetails");
        Map<String, Property> modelProperties = model.getProperties();

        // Keep a reference to the property definitions
        Property domainPropertyRef = modelProperties.get("domain");
        Property usernamePropertyRef = modelProperties.get("username");
        Property passwordPropertyRef = modelProperties.get("password");

        // Remove all entries from the underlying linkedHashMap
        modelProperties.clear();

        // Add your own keys in a specific order
        Map<String, Property> orderedPropertyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        orderedPropertyMap.put("domain", domainPropertyRef);
        orderedPropertyMap.put("username", usernamePropertyRef);
        orderedPropertyMap.put("password", passwordPropertyRef);
        orderedPropertyMap.put("..rest..", otherPropertyRef);

        model.setProperties(orderedPropertyMap);
        return swagger;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final DocumentationType documentationType) {
        return SWAGGER_2.equals(documentationType);
    }
}


@Configuration
class SwaggerConf {
  @Bean
  public PropertyOrderTransformationFilter propertyOrderTransformationFilter () {
     return new PropertyOrderTransformationFilter ();
  }
}
```

Comment: that's quiet cool and it works so thanks :)
Although it does look like cutting fruits with a sword so I'll see the app's performance before implementing it.